# Detailed video lecture series that follows "Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach" by Henessy Patterson

Tags: self-learning, resource-request, architecture

I want to do self-study for Computer Architecture and I wish I could get hold of a detailed video lecture series that goes hand in hand with the classic text "Computer Architecture: A Quantitative Approach" by Hennessy and Patterson.

The video lecture series would help me understand the concepts in the said book in a better manner, because without an instructor I feel I might not get to extract the most of the subject.

Comment: Have you checked UCBerkeley? That would be a fairly obvious source, especially now, with coronavirus.

Comment: Can you provide me the link as to where to search for?

Comment: Sorry. I just know Patterson taught there. You realize that this would be a very advanced course, I hope.

Comment: Yes I realize and as you said about corona virus, in this quarantine it shall be best to utilize the time to the fullest